# Question about Polynomial and finding a model between two equation?

Tags: polynomials

The question is 
for 1980, trough 1990, the total amount, $A$ (in billions of dollars), spent by Americans for the farm foods can be modeled by $$ A = -0.035t^2 + 15.9t + 267.6$$
where $t=0$ represents 1980. The amount, $F$ (in billions of dollars), paid to farmers can be modeled  by $$ F = 0.156t^2 + 0.475t + 81.5 $$ Find the model that represents the amount that was spent on processing, packaging and marketing the food.

For this problem I don't even understand what i have to do to solve it? Do i use the calculator, if so how would i do it? Any ideas on how to solve them?

Comment: One interpretation: $A$ is what consumers spent for the products and $F$ is what farmers earned so the difference $A-F$ is the amount of money that went elsewhere (processing, packaging, marketing, profits for shops carrying the products etc.).

Comment: Oh so it was just a difference between A and F?

Comment: This is the only sensible interpretation imo given just the information you have in your question. However "processing, packaging and marketing the food" is not the only way money can go as it ignores profits for shops, transport etc. If we assume that the question is meant to include all these things then $A-F$ is correct.